# How change the object name that displays on console?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I really want to know if this is possible?

The circled object is generated by jQuery, and its with the custom name.

Please advise, how can I name a object like that. Thank you very much!!!

[image]

> var obj = [{ a : 1 , b : 2 }]
>
> console.log (obj)

Can you give me an example that you can change the object name to "Foo" with above object and simple with `console.log`

Comment: yes it's possible :) just I don't know why do you want to rename jq object

Comment: I dont want to rename jq object, i want to rename my own obj

Comment: You have to override [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method of your object.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek can you specify?

Comment: @Till No. Read the ^$^#$# manual (linked).

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I doubt you understand my question, please kindly provide example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `toString` method.

A very shorthand example:

```
console.log( ""+{toString:()=>'My Object'} );
// prints: My Object
```

#### How?

`toString` is called whenever the object in question is demanded in context of a string value. This happens when you're appending to a string or forcing the conversion with the `toString()` method.

If you have classes, you can do it as a prototype:

```
function MyClass () { /*...*/ }
MyClass.prototype.toString =()=> 'Not MyClass';
```

Whether the effect is seen in object traversal depends on when or if `toString` will be called. Otherwise it may be browser specific.

#### Using Browser / Traversal views

This worked in Chrome:

```
var x = {};
x.y = function(){};
console.log(new x.y); // prints: x.y {}
```

It relies on the source code where the function was created. Note no function name! If I had, this is what would happen:

```
var x = {};
x.y = function X (){};
console.log(new x.y); // prints: X {}
```

Comment: the screen shot was generated by simply print the object without convert it to "String", can you give me a example that you can print this object obj = { a : 1 , b : 2 } with the name "Foo" by simple console.log(  obj )

Comment: This is the closest you can do in exactly the examples above. Chrome / FF (that i've just tested) both don't use this for their traversal and print the source code variable names that were used to construct the object. As in, there is literally a `jQuery.fn.init` object.

Comment: @Till I'll update my answer as there _is sort of_ a way to do it.